# Does ipad app with only landscape mode will be accepted by apple or not

Tags: ios, ipad, landscape

I have app in which i have used rotation for the app fixed to landscape apple will accept the app or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Why not. You can develop app for one orientation.

Comment: it mean  i have to fixed orientation for view controller in landscape only like  return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);